# How supported Headers and Media Types are "discovered" with HATEOAS?

Tags: rest, hateoas, hal, media-type

Simply put, imagine a particular resource can be served using different Media Types (e.g. `application/vnd.com.example.resource-v1+json` and `application/vnd.com.example.resource-v2+json`).

My question is, how does a client know of these options for a RESTful Hypermedia-driven service (using HATEOAS)?

I see HAL provides a [`type`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal#name-type) and a [`profile`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal#name-profile) field that seems to be related ([here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal#name-media-type-parameters)), but I don't see much adoption or examples on whether/how these fields should be used to communicate the supported Media Types for the resource.

Comment: IMO it shouldn't be the server who advertises which media types it thinks might be the best for that resource but the client telling the server which media types it supports so that the server can generate a response the client told it is able to understand and process. It is all about interoperability. Media types should also be expressive enough to describe the resource to the client but in the same vein general enough to be reuseable for other tasks and thus find wide adoption. Look at HTML i.e. its elements are well defined and expressive enough to show humans all kind of different data.

Answer (score 0):

One option I've used for this in the past is the Link header, with a an `alternate` rel. For example:

```
Link: </foo>; rel="alternate" type="text/csv" title="CSV version"
```